# How do you test an object's state in a unit test while also avoiding public variables?

Tags: unit-testing

Let's say I have a method that performs a computation and then changes the state of an object. But I also want to avoid using public variables as well as getters and setters.

I can seperate the computation into its own separate function and unit test that function. But how would I test the state of the object as well, while also avoiding public variables and getter / setter methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe not quite kosher, but you could subclass your original class as the test case and use protected variables.

Answer (score 0):

test the state of the object using the public method that changes the state of the object and then assert that the state of the object is indeed what it should be